# mail should come with sender name not from root

Tags: email, smtp

When I am sending mail by using below command in RHEL 7.4 server, I am receiving mail from `root@<server name with fqdn>`.

```
echo test|mailx -S smtp=mail.sap.corp -s "test" -v venkatesh.vishwanatham@aaa.com
```

But I want mail to be received like as below, please tell me what configuration needs to be changed in server.

```
from:
venkatesh,vishwanatham
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anywhere in your example where you're doing anything to set a from header.

```
echo test | mailx -S smtp=mail.sap.corp -s "test" -v -r venkatesh.vishwanatham@aaa.com venkatesh.vishwanatham@aaa.com
```

If your version of `mailx` supports `-r` to set the from address, you can add that option.

If it doesn't you can try the option below.  The first instance of the email address for venkatesh.vishwanatham is going to be used as the recipient.  Passing `-- -f <address>` should cause mailx to ignore that option and pass it directly to the mailer.

Option 2:

```
echo test | mailx -S smtp=mail.sap.corp -s "test" -v venkatesh.vishwanatham@aaa.com -- -f venkatesh.vishwanatham@aaa.com
```